# What do I need to do to configure a new iPhone project so it can be seen as the same as my current iPhone app in the Appstore?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I currently have an app in the Appstore. I need to make changes to the app, but they are significant enough that we've decided it would be easier to create a new Xcode project from scratch rather than modify our existing project. I don't fully understand everything that goes into an iPhone application, just enough to support the code and make basic changes. But I assume that the binary I upload to the Appstore, to replace my existing code there, needs to be similar enough so Apples sees it as the "same" code. What things in the new project do I need to make sure are the same as the old project so Apple knows it's the "same" app?

I've compared the Info.plist file in both projects to make sure they're the same. I only needed to change the bundle identifier in the new project to match the old. Also, the Product Name has been modified to be the same. I don't know if these changes are necessary, but they are the sort of things that I think need to be the same. Are there others? If so, what are they?

Answer (score 2):

The **only** thing that matters, as far as the app store is concerned, is the app id (Bundle identifier).  You can rename the app, change the icon, upload an entirely different program, whatever.  As long as the app id matches, the store considers it the same.

Answer (score 1):

Other things I would check are the Build Settings if the defaults are not suitable or the Code is having issues compiling and the Build Phases and Build Rules for all your Targets.

Essentially if your Code compiles fine and you have no issues within the Application then the Bundle Identifier and the name (Basically the Info.plist) needs to be the same to replicate.

Edit: If you have migrated from an older Xcode version then you may have different Build Settings and Build Phases. I would just see if compilation is okay and the App works properly in functionality under all your Targets

Comment: The new project compiles just fine. So I verified that the Info.plist file is named the same as well as the Bundle identifier. Thanks.